# Is there a concise way to say "to send a text message"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Is there a concise way to say "to send a text message (to)" in Spanish, like we say "to text" in English?

I typed "I texted her" into Google Translate, and it said "le envié un mensaje de texto". Maybe that can be shortened to "le envié un mensaje", but that is still a bit verbose, and possibly a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @wimi Why did you delete my answer?? It shows two different ways of saying send a text message in Spanish. I think you are very **unfair**.

Comment: @RubioRic My answer provides 2 translation of send a text message. How can you not see that??

Comment: @Lambie A lo mejor se te escapó una mala palabra mientras estabas respondiendo

Comment: No entiendo. No hay ninguna mala palabra.

Comment: @Lambie OP was asking explicitly for a concise way. Not for a translation. Notice that such longer translation is already included in the question. On the other hand no services for sending messages were requested. In any case, I didn't remove anything nor suggested that action.

Answer (score 7):

The verb "textear" can be used. According to https://dle.rae.es/textear it is more common in America.

1. intr. Bol., Cuba, EE. UU., El Salv., Méx., Nic., P. Rico y Ur. mensajear. U. t. c. tr.

Comment: No es el caso de la Argentina, en donde a cualquiera que le preguntés te va a decir que es incorrecto el uso de esa palabra. Aunque también es cierto que usamos ‘anglicismos’ que son mucho peores y no los reconocemos como tal,  somos raros...

Answer (score 2):

En castellano es mucho más difícil generar nuevos verbos a partir de los sustantivos existentes. Esto puede deberse a que: no queda bien, no nos gusta o simplemente porque somos (lingüísticamente) fijistas.

Pienso que **mensajear** <del>sería un término muy original para usar, pero por desgracia la palabra no es reconocida</del> es el mejor término que puede usarse como equivalente (¡la palabra está registrada!). En la práctica no veo que sea muy usada esta palabra, pero en este caso quedaría **‘le mensajeé (a ella)’**.

Otra posibilidad que es más común sería emplear el término **escribir**, es decir ‘**le escribí (a ella)**'. ‘Pero ese término es ambiguo’—me dirás. Aunque puede interpretarse como ‘escribir una postal’, lo cierto es que nadie hace eso hoy en día. Más aún, el mensaje es digital y por lo general no importa exactamente por cuál plataforma le escribiste, lo que importa es que le escribiste y punto.

Comment: to send a text message no pide un nuevo verbo: mandar o enviar un mensaje de texto. Sin mensaje de texto la respuesta no funciona.

Comment: @Lambie al contrario, en castellano podemos prescindir del objeto si está sobreentendido, como sucede en estos casos. Creo que el problema reside en que tu análisis es *sintáctico*, el mío es *semántico*. Encontrame a alguien que diga ‘le escribí un mensaje de texto’ en lugar de ‘le escribí’ y te regalo una moto

Comment: "le escribí [una carta, una nota, un memorándum, un mensaje] etc. text message = mensaje de texto. En todo caso, no deberian (wimi)  de haber borrado mi respuesta. Me pregunto lo que pasa aqui en este foro. Es una total falta de ética.

Comment: @Lambie No me queda claro cuál era tu aporte. El OP está preguntando por una forma *concisa* de decirlo (en una o dos palabras), no está pidiendo una traducción *per se*.

Comment: Vale pero eso no valida borrar mi respuesta.